# React wait for const to have value before rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am wanting to render the user's name and balance, however the balance renders before the name, but I want them to render together, at the same time. Therefore I assume that the firstName has not been fetched when the balance has, therefore I imagine I would need to test against this - hence why I have the `while` loop.

```
  renderBalanceAndName() {
    const balance = this.context.account.getIn(['balance', 'total']);
    const firstName = this.context.account.getIn(['accountDetails', 'data', 'firstName']);

    while (firstName !== null) {
      return (
        <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>,
        <span>{firstName} {" "} &mdash; {" "}
        <Money value={balance} /></span>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>
    )
  },

  renderAccountDetails() {
    const balancePending = this.context.account.getIn(['balance', 'pending']);

    return (
      <div style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
        <span style={styles.balance} className="qa-nav-balance-and-name">
          {balancePending && <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>}
          {!balancePending && this.renderBalanceAndName(this.context.account)}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  },
```

Comment: What is `this.context.account.getIn` ? Does it return a `Promise` ?

Comment: no, this is brought in from an external place. However that should not be of use anyway because I'd need to render both items then either is not null

Comment: So `this.context.account.getIn` is synchronous ? How is your `while` different from an `if` statement ?

Comment: What you need is *Promise.all*, with that you can run multiple promises in parallel, wait for all of them to finish and then do something.

Comment: @Robert yes this is what I am wanting to use. However, could you provide an example in relation to my code above? Thanks.

Comment: @kouak my `while` is different from an `if` because it will loop until it is not `null` wont it?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `firstName` is available in the `prop`. If no, return the `<Spinner/>`

```
renderBalanceAndName() {
    const balance = this.context.account.getIn(['balance', 'total']);
    const firstName = this.context.account.getIn(['accountDetails', 'data', 'firstName'])
    if(!firstName) //check if firstName is available.
      return (
        <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>
      )

    while (firstName !== null) {
      return (
        <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>,
        <span>{firstName} {" "} &mdash; {" "}
        <Money value={balance} /></span>
      );
    }
  },

  renderAccountDetails() {
    const balancePending = this.context.account.getIn(['balance', 'pending']);

    return (
      <div style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
        <span style={styles.balance} className="qa-nav-balance-and-name">
          {balancePending && <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>}
          {!balancePending && this.renderBalanceAndName(this.context.account)}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

As i understand from your code, .. account.getIn.. are  asynchronous call.

```
You should use states. Create a store and action file. Something like below

     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
             //  whenver there is change in appstore call update data function 
              AppStore.addListener(() => this.updateData());
        }
        updateData() {
          // Update state from appstore data. This will trigger render function
            this.setState({
                ...AppStore.getState()
            });  
        }
    renderBalanceAndName() {
        //Fetch data  state.
        const balance = this.state.balance;
        const firstName = this.state.firstName;

        while (firstName !== null) {
          return (
            <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>,
            <span>{firstName} {" "} &mdash; {" "}
            <Money value={balance} /></span>
          );
        }

        return (
          <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>
        )
      },

      renderAccountDetails() {
        const balancePending = this.context.account.getIn(['balance', 'pending']);

        return (
          <div style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
            <span style={styles.balance} className="qa-nav-balance-and-name">
              {balancePending && <Spinner size={theme.fontSize.alpha}/>}
              {!balancePending && this.renderBalanceAndName(this.context.account)}
            </span>
          </div>
        );
      }




And your store file:


  case "dataUpdated": {
    state = state.set(payload.key, payload.value);
    return state;
  }


and your action file something like below:

Action file: will be something like below:

.

    .
    .
      FETCH_DATA(refKey) { 
          let _this = this;
 // async call or value updates below:
          let response = this.context.account.getIn(['balance', 'total']);
          _this.dispatch({
              action: "dataUpdated",
              ACQUDATA: response
            });
      }
      ....



I havn't tested above code for syntax and there can be some syntax issue. This is just for understanding approach. 

Regards,
sachin
```

Comment: I dont wish to create a new file. The solution as I am aware is to use a `promise` rather than actually creating an Action file. I would prefer to use a `promise` as stated above. Thanks.